# REGEX - How to replace <br /> with </p> <p> inside a single paragraph

Tags: html, regex, html-parsing

This is a single paragraph which I want to replace <br/> with </p> <p> :

> ```
> <p>Test fahfdjfhsdljfhshfsdfsfsdfd<br/>
>     fhdsjhfjsfhsjfhskhfshfhdsfskhfhsdf<br/>
>     hjhfjshfksdfjshjfhsjkdf</p>
> ```

Expected result:

> ```
> <p>Test fahfdjfhsdljfhshfsdfsfsdfd</p>
>     <p>fhdsjhfjsfhsjfhskhfshfhdsfskhfhsdf</p>
>     <p>hjhfjshfksdfjshjfhsjkdf</p>
> ```

How do I use regex to have this expected result? Actually, I have other <br/> outside of that paragraph but I don't want to change it when changing the above code.
Thank you.

Comment: You have to specify a language. HTML+regex makes no sense. For example, Python has `re` module for using regexes.

Comment: Do you have a specific restriction that prevents you from using HTML functions or you're just no aware of them?

Comment: @ForceBru: I'm using the Ruby on Rails, so I use the string.gsub() to replace the <br/>

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: Same as above answer.

Comment: How do you identify "this" paragraph? Is there just one?

Comment: I just need to identify any paragraph which has <br/> inside and replace them as above description.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are always a pair of `<p></p>` surrounding the text, then the problem becomes:

> How to replace `<br/>` with `</p></p>`

and the answer to that should be replace `<br\/?>[\s]*?\n?[\s]*` with `</p>\n</p>`

The Regex first find the `<br>` or `<br/>`, then match as less space as it can before the next line character, which might not exist, followed by spaces.